# How can I make the summation more dynamic in my code

Tags: python

This is my code that uses a text file to do some calculations. I want to make my code more dynamic rather than static the way it is right now, I need some help on how I can shorten the code more specifically the part where I am calculating the sum. I am a bit new to python so please bear with me.

```
import numpy as np
import math

# Getting all the values in the file accept the first line
file = open("history.txt", "r")
next(file)
lines = np.array([list(map(int,line.split())) for line in file])
mylist=np.unique(lines,axis=0)
print(f"Positive entries: {len(mylist)}")
file.close()
# Getting the first line of the file
file = open("history.txt", "r")
first_line = [list(map(int,line.split())) for line in file]
No_items = first_line[0][1]
No_Customers = first_line[0][0]
file.close()
# Creating a zeros array
vectors = np.zeros((No_items,No_Customers))
rows = [i[1] - 1 for i in lines]
# print(rows)
columns = [x[0] - 1 for x in lines]
# print(columns)
vectors[rows, columns] = 1
print(vectors)

number_of_vectors = len(vectors) * (len(vectors) - 1)

def calc_angle(x, y):
    norm_x = np.linalg.norm(x)
    norm_y = np.linalg.norm(y)
    cos_theta = np.dot(x, y) / (norm_x * norm_y)
    theta = math.degrees(math.acos(cos_theta))
    return theta

sum = (calc_angle(vectors[0],vectors[1]) + calc_angle(vectors[0],vectors[2]) + calc_angle(vectors[0],vectors[3]) + calc_angle(vectors[0],vectors[4]) 
+ calc_angle(vectors[1],vectors[0]) + calc_angle(vectors[1],vectors[2]) + calc_angle(vectors[1],vectors[3]) + calc_angle(vectors[1],vectors[4]) 
+ calc_angle(vectors[2],vectors[0])  + calc_angle(vectors[2],vectors[1]) + calc_angle(vectors[2],vectors[3]) + calc_angle(vectors[2],vectors[4]) 
+ calc_angle(vectors[3],vectors[0])  + calc_angle(vectors[3],vectors[1]) + calc_angle(vectors[3],vectors[2]) + calc_angle(vectors[3],vectors[4])
+ calc_angle(vectors[4],vectors[0])  + calc_angle(vectors[4],vectors[1]) + calc_angle(vectors[4],vectors[2]) + calc_angle(vectors[4],vectors[3]))

print(sum/number_of_vectors)
```

Comment: `I want to make my code more dynamic rather than static` - what does that mean?

Comment: What is the shape of `vectors`

Comment: As you can see when I am calculating the sum the values are hardcoded, so I wanted an easier way to calculate the sum rather than me having to hardcode all the values in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use for loops atall? You can do this in a vectorized way by doing this. -

#### Vectorized to work as pairwise

Here is a completely vectorized approach without using np.vectorize signatures. This takes in a matrix containing row vectors and runs a pairwise calc_angle on it before taking a sum.

```
def calc_angle(vectors):
    norm = np.linalg.norm(vectors, axis=-1)
    cos_theta = np.dot(vectors,vectors.T) / np.outer(norm,norm)
    theta = np.degrees(np.arccos(cos_theta))
    
    np.fill_diagonal(theta, 0)
    return theta

np.sum(calc_angle(vectors)) #Takes in one set of vectors
```

#### Vectorized to work for 2 independent vectors

This takes in 2 independent vectors (or sets of vectors) as inputs instead of one matrix. Allows you to work with 2 different sets of vectors as well if you don't want to do pairwise distances among the same input vectors.

```
def calc_angle(x, y):
    norm_x = np.linalg.norm(x, axis=-1)
    norm_y = np.linalg.norm(y, axis=-1)
    cos_theta = np.dot(x,y.T) / np.outer(norm_x,norm_y)
    theta = np.degrees(np.arccos(cos_theta))
    
    np.fill_diagonal(theta, 0)
    return theta

np.sum(calc_angle(vectors, vectors)) #Takes 2 sets of vectors (could be same)
```

#### Using np.vectorize

It's not very efficient, but helps when you are stuck with non-vectorizable code.

```
def calc_angle(x, y):
    norm_x = np.linalg.norm(x)
    norm_y = np.linalg.norm(y)
    cos_theta = np.dot(x,y) / (norm_x * norm_y)
    theta = np.degrees(np.arccos(cos_theta))
    return theta

calc_angle_vec = np.vectorize(calc_angle, signature='(k),(k)->()')

sums = calc_angle_vec(vectors[None,:,:], vectors[:,None,:])
np.fill_diagonal(sums, 0)
output = np.sum(sums)
```

**Broad idea -**

1. These approaches calculate pairwise calc_angle between all vectors by taking norm over the last axis
2. Then the dot of the matrices in numerator normalized by the outer of the norms give you the distances
3. The distances are then passed to numpy functions which are vectorized and turn them into corresponding degrees
4. Next, fill diagonals by 0 (because they are the same vectors)
5. Finally reduce the matrix with a `np.sum`.
6. **Note:** I have changed the math functions to equivalent NumPy functions because they support vectorization.

---

Comment: Ok, this is a bit too complicated for me, but it works. Thank you!  <3

Comment: Updating my answer

Comment: The second approach will be significantly faster than any other approach mentioned in other answers, since it is vectorized

Comment: Its super simple once you write and run each line separately.

Comment: moved the second one to the top as it should be the right way to solve this via numpy. Hope that helps. let me know incase of any questions.

Comment: Further simplified my answer to work only as a pairwise method, instead of taking 2 input sets of vectors.

Answer (score 2):

For calculating the sum you can do this:

```
total = 0 #using sum is not recommended as it is an in-built variable
for i in range(5):
       for j in range(5):
           if i!= j:
               total += calc_angle(vectors[i],vectors[j])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested loops to iterate over the two dimensions:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if i != j:
            sum += calc_angle(vectors[i],vectors[j])
```

You could also use the built-in `sum` function with a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). In that case you would want to give the variable a different name so as not to shadow the function.

```
total = sum(calc_angle(vectors[i], vectors[j]) for i in range(5) for j in range(5) if i != j)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is working. You have also educated me that sum is a built-in function and that I should use a different variable name. Every day I learn something new.

Comment: you can avoid using for loops completely, the beauty of numpy is to be able to vectorize code.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def sum_angles(rows, cols):
    total = 0
    for i in range(row):
       for j in range(col):
           total = total + calc_angle(i, j)
    return total/(rows*cols)
```

You can make it as a function.